# DiscordUtils not getting installed properly

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to install DiscordUtils in my discord.py bot but I am getting the error.. `Import "DiscordUtils" could not be resolved` I have already tried `pip install DiscordUtils` and `pip install DiscordUtils[voice]`
This is what my site-packages looks like..

[image]

Whenever I try to install it again, all I get is requirement already satisfied. All my other imports work 100% fine. How can I fix this issue? Is this a Path issue?

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: @Dominik `Import "DiscordUtils" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports`

Comment: You're most likely not using the correct interpreter. The package is installed under python39. You have to make sure you're using that precise interpreter. You could have python, python3, python39, etc, as interpreters. Use `python -m pip install Discord Utils` but using the interpreter that you want